# Git save branch with data from previous branches

Tags: git, github

I have a repository(Repository1) and used this structure:

- branch1 - only has folders of branch1
- branch2 - has folders of branch1 + branch2
- branch3 - has folders of branch3 + branch2 + branch1

At some point i created a new repository(Repository2) and created branch4 and as it was new repository i forgot to copy data of previous branch3+2+1 into it.
Now i realized i don't really need Repository2 and i want to add my commits of branch4 into Repository1 but need to prepend it with older branches data, so branch4 need to have folders of branch3+2+1.

So i think i need to do something like this: create new branch4 from branch3 on Repository1 so it has all my previous data. Add new commits from Repository2 on top of it, but i'm not sure how to do it exactly without screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add Repository2 as origin to Repository1 and merge it with `--allow-unrelated-histories`, then remove Repository2 origin and continue working from Repository1.